# I want to filter column with a character

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter the column NAME with just one letter "o".
DataFrame:

| NAME | HOBBY |
| --- | --- |
| John | football |
| Kelly | chess |

`df["NAME"].filter(like ="o")`

I am looking for an output:

| NAME | HOBBY |
| --- | --- |
| John | football |

Comment: If my answer helped, I would appreciate it if you could accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .contains to filter only the rows where name contains a lower case 'o'.

Using the below df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'NAME' : ['John', 'Kelly'],
                   'HOBBY' : ['football', 'chess']})
```

Then you can use .loc and .contains to filter on desired rows:

```
  df.loc[df['NAME'].str.contains('o')]
```

Output:

```
   NAME     HOBBY
0  John  football
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help. it is working.

Comment: @Tashi if this has solved your problem, it would be great if you could accept it (the tick mark on the left) and maybe upvote :)